# Forward geocoding and zoom to fit multiple locations

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, clgeocoder

The following is the code I have used to load mapview.

```
- (void)getLatLongCoordinates:(NSString*) addressStr firstNameTitle:(NSString*) firstNamesTitle lastNameTitle:(NSString*) lastNamesTitle       { 
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressStr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    self.placemarksArray = placemarks;
    CLPlacemark *placeInfo = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

    mapCenter.latitude = placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude;
    mapCenter.longitude = placeInfo.location.coordinate.latitude;
    [annotationPoint setCoordinate:mapCenter];

    [annotationPointsArray addObject:annotationPoint];

    addAnnotation = [[[MyAddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapCenter title:firstNamesTitle SubTitle:lastNamesTitle ]autorelease];
    addAnnotation.firstNameTitle = firstNamesTitle;
    addAnnotation.lastNameTitle = lastNamesTitle;

[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
}];
```

}

I need to call the the method `[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:mapView withArray:annotationPointsArray];`
 to fit all the contacts in the mapview at the maximum zoom level. Till the previous implementations I have been successfully using the following code. But since I am using blocks now, I am a bit confused about when to call this method. I need to obtain all the location coordinates before I call this method and pass the array to it.

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapViews withArray:(NSArray*)anAnnotationArray
{
if([mapViews.annotations count] == 0) return;

CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;



for(MKPointAnnotation* annotation in anAnnotationArray)
{
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;     
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; 

region = [mapViews regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

Where is the right place in the above piece of code to call the above method or do I need to find some other way to do this.

Edit: I avoided using the `mapCenter` and accessed the co-ordinates directly from `placeInfo` in the `getLatLongCoordinates` method and I am getting it right and the issue is solved. But I am still bemused, why the first way didn't work.

Comment: call this [self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:mapView withArray:annotationPointsArray]; after [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

Comment: or simply call this mehod - (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations { 

    if ([mMapView.annotations count] == 0) return;
    int i = 0;
    MKMapPoint points[[mMapView.annotations count]];

    //build array of annotation points
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in [mMapView annotations]){
         points[i++] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
    }

    MKPolygon *poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:i];
    [mMapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([poly boundingMapRect]) animated:YES]; 
}this will fit the map

Comment: at present from where u are calling that method please update with some code

Comment: Just after `[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];`. The problem is that irrespcetive of the location, the mapview zooms to central asian region.

Comment: call after the block execution completes and check

Comment: what  happened it workedor not..?

Comment: Its hard to find where the block completes execution.

Comment: call before closing this method and try - (void)getLatLongCoordinates:(NSString*) addressStr firstNameTitle:(NSString*) firstNamesTitle lastNameTitle:(NSString*) lastNamesTitle       {

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my of my case

generally i call this method after i add annotation in my mapview..so it best way is to call this method after add annotationView to mapVIEW.

Comment: I have multiple locations and I am not getting the zoom range correctly. It always zooms to the central Asia part, whatever the location maybe.

Answer (score 0):

use this code  `zoomToFitMapAnnotations`

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView_
{
    if([mapView_.annotations count] == 0)
        return;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

    for(CKMapAnnotationView* annotation in mapView_.annotations)
    {
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    }
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
    region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

    region = [mapView_ regionThatFits:region];


    [mapView_ setRegion:[self validRegion:region] animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT:** to call this function after load annotations

```
[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:mapView];
```